# Cartesian to quaternion glm

Tags: c++, math, rotation, glm-math

I have a vector pointing in the direction I need to rotate, but  I need to convert it to a quaternion first. I cannot find anything about converting from cartesian coordinates to quaternions in glm. Does such a function exist?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe these will help you out. They can be found on their website in the API documents for v0.9.6:

```
GLM_FUNC_DECL tvec4<T, P> glm::rotate( tquat<T,P> const &q, tvec4<T,P> const &v )   

Rotates a 4 components vector by a quaternion.    
See also GLM_GTX_quaternion  


GLM_FUNC_DECL tquat<T, P> glm::rotation( tvec3<T,P> const &orig, tvec3<T,P> const &dest )

Compute the rotation between two vectors.    
param orig vector, needs to be normalized param dest vector, needs to be normalized    
See also GLM_GTX_quaternion
```

and

```
template<typename T, precision P>  
GLM_FUNC_DECL tvec3<T,P>  rotate( tquat<T,P> const &q, tvec3<T,P> const &v ) 

template<typename T, precision P>  
GLM_FUNC_DECL tvec4<T,P>  rotate( tquat<T,P> const &q, tvec4<T,P> const &v ) 

template<typename T, precision P>  
GLM_FUNC_DECL tquat<T,P>  rotation( tvec3<T,P> const &orig, tvec3<T,P> const &dest ) 

template<typename T, precision P>  
GLM_FUNC_DECL tquat<T,P>  shortMix( tquat<T, P> const &x, tquat<T, P> const &y, T const &a ) 

template<typename T, precision P>  
GLM_FUNC_DECL tquat<T,P>  squad( tquat<T,P> const &q1, tquat<T,P> const &q2, tquat<T,P> const &s1, tquat<T,P> const &s2, T const &h ) 

template<typename T, precision P>  
GLM_FUNC_DECL tmat3x3<T,P>  toMat3( tquat<T,P> const &x ) 

template<typename T, precision P>  
GLM_FUNC_DECL tmat4x4<T,P>  toMat4( tquat<T,P> const &x )  

template<typename T, precision P>  
GLM_FUNC_DECL tquat<T,P>  toQuat( tmat3x3<T,P> const &x ) 

template<typename T, precision P>  
GLM_FUNC_DECL tquat<T,P>  toQuat( tmat4x4<T,P> const &x )
```

Within these list of functions; there are functions that will allow you to rotate using a quaternion from using two vectors that returns a quaternion, to convert to and from a matrix3x3 or 4x4 and other useful functions.